# Java add/remove row to JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to figure out how to add and remove rows from a JTabel. I want to remove rows based on the first column which is a unique ID.

I am currently creating my table like this:

```
       String[] colName = new String[] {
           "ID#", "Country", "Name", "Page titel", "Page URL", "Time"
       };
       Object[][] products = new Object[][] {
           {
               "867954", "USA", "Todd", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:04:13"
           }, {
               "522532", "USA", "Bob", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:04:29"
           }, {
               "4213532", "USA", "Bill", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:04:25"
           }, {
               "5135132", "USA", "Mary", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:06:23"
           }
       };


       table = new JTable(products, colName);
```

How could i add a new row and delete the row with ID # `867954` ?

Comment: progrmmatically or based or with an input event? In all cases you have to deal with `jtable.getModel()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it if you use `DefaultTableModel`:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(products, colName);
table = new JTable(dtm);
```

Now you can add and remove rows:

```
dtm.removeRow(0); //remove first row
dtm.addRow(new Object[]{...});//add row
```

If you want to delete a row based on the ID, you can search for row with that ID and remove it then:

```
String searchedId = "867954";//ID of the product to remove from the table
int row = -1;//index of row or -1 if not found

//search for the row based on the ID in the first column
for(int i=0;i<dtm.getRowCount();++i)
    if(dtm.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(searchedId))
    {
        row = i;
        break;
    }

if(row != -1)
    dtm.removeRow(row);//remove row

else
    ...//not found
```

Comment: How would i delete a row based on the ID in column 1?